# Cannot watch expressions of GWT under debug mode in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt

I am using `GWT 2.8` with `GWT plugin v.3` and `Tomcat 8` in `Eclipse`.

When I debug the project, breakpoints are working fine, but I can't watch expression, it shows reference error.

Does anyone has the same issue?

I read some related question which says using Google Plugin will be fine, but Google Plugin doesn't support `Java 8`.

Why it happens and how I solve it?

Comment: This should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105469/how-to-debug-using-superdev-mode

Answer (score 1):

With GWT 2.8 and SuperDev Mode you have to change your debugging habbits a bit. On the server side the things stay the same, but on the client side you have to use the browser for debugging. Use `GWT.debugger` to add breakpoints in the code or set JS breakpoints in your browsers developer tools.

You also have to use the developer tools to see the expressions. Keep in mind to turn on source maps in your browser preferences. Eventually you have to use the `-noincremental` parameter in your run configuration to see the java variables.

Comment: Thanks you for answering my question, now I am using Chrome with -noincremental argument. the debugger is working fine.

Comment: Could you possibly explain in detail how to use the -noincremental parameter in your run configuration to see the java variables?